# Appcelerator - How to detect redrawing of a TableView on iOS

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I need to detect when the TableView is redrawed on iOS each time I add a new row.

In android I'm able to use the eventListener 'postlayout' but in iOS when I add a new row this event doesn't fired.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've hit a parity bug. Could you report this which I [can't find](https://jira.appcelerator.org/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20TIMOB%20AND%20text%20~%20%22ios%20tableview%20postlayout%22) a JIRA ticket for. Could you create one with example code, expected and actual results?

As a workaround, you might be able to add an event listener on that event to the parent view of the table.